# Add elements of a list at the end of each tuple of a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list with some static elements:

```
['foo', 1, '', 0]
```

And I have a list of tuples:

```
[('val1', 9), ('val2', 'val3'), ('val4', '')]
```

How can I add the elements of a list at the end of each tuple of a list of tuples?

**Output**

```
[
('val1', 9, 'foo', 1, '', 0),
('val2', 'val3', 'foo', 1, '', 0),
('val4', '', 'foo', 1, '', 0)
]
```

Comment: Note that tuples cannot be extended with new elements. Are you fine with a list of new tuples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just rebuild the tuple list using addition of tuples:

```
elts = ['foo', 1, '', 0]
t = [('val1', 9), ('val2', 'val3'), ('val4', '')]

result = [e+tuple(elts) for e in t]
```

result:

```
[('val1', 9, 'foo', 1, '', 0),
 ('val2', 'val3', 'foo', 1, '', 0),
 ('val4', '', 'foo', 1, '', 0)]
```

you may want to set `elts` as `tuple` to avoid the conversion in the loop:

```
elts = ['foo', 1, '', 0] # or elts = tuple(elts) if you have an existing list
result = [e+elts for e in t]
```

Comment: It change something if I convert to tuple inside the list comprehension or if I change it before? Like performance or something like that.

Comment: tuples use less memory than lists because they're not resizable. not working in-place means that a copy of the existing data is made, and a new tuple is created. Unless you're using a loop and lists (and not a comprehension)

Answer (score 1):

In python, tuples are immutable collections, meaning you cannot modify the elements within it. However, you *can* reassign the variable to a new tuple, which can be used much like lists.

```
list1 = ['foo', 1, '', 0]
list2 = [('val1', 9), ('val2', 'val3'), ('val4', '')]
endlist = []
for x in range(len(list2)):
    endlist += [tuple(list2[x]) + tuple(list1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tuple unpacking for this:

```
elts = ['foo', 1, '', 0]
t = [('val1', 9), ('val2', 'val3'), ('val4', '')]

result = [(*t_item, *elts) for t_item in t]
```

And it gives:

```
[('val1', 9, 'foo', 1, '', 0),
 ('val2', 'val3', 'foo', 1, '', 0),
 ('val4', '', 'foo', 1, '', 0)]
```

---

It is a little bit faster than https://stackoverflow.com/a/54409510/8056572 with large list `t`:

```
elts = ['foo', 1, '', 0]
t = [('val1', 9), ('val2', 'val3'), ('val4', '')] * 1000

%timeit [(*t_item, *elts) for t_item in t]
307 µs ± 2.45 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit [e + tuple(elts) for e in t]
432 µs ± 10.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```